# how to get the color of the rectangle in datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I have a datagridview like this [image]

then I want to get the colors in the rectangle of my cell-click.
how to get that color? I've been looking for but not finding.
Please help me. thanks

I want to get the color in datagridview when the user clicks ok, because to give color map. I made the gis application.

This code is to make the data gridview,

Dim dtCloned As New DataTable
            Dim imagecolumn As DataColumn = New DataColumn
            imagecolumn.DataType = GetType(Bitmap)
            imagecolumn.ColumnName = "Symbol"
            dtCloned.Columns.Add(imagecolumn)
            dtCloned.Columns.Add("Value")
            dtCloned.Columns.Add("Legend")

```
        For i As Integer = 0 To sf.Categories.Count - 1
            Dim r As DataRow = dtCloned.NewRow
            Dim bmp As New Bitmap(50, 15)
            Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Item(i)
            Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromOle(scheme.GraduatedColor((i) / sf.Categories.Count)))
            g.FillRectangle(Brush, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
            g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
            r(0) = bmp
            r(1) = category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1)
            r(2) = category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1)
            dtCloned.Rows.Add(r)
        Next
        DataGVSymUnique.DataSource = dtCloned
        For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGVSymUnique.Columns
            c.Width = 145
            c.ReadOnly = True
        Next
        DataGVSymUnique.Columns("Legend").ReadOnly = False
```

Comment: There are a few different ways this can be done. Are they going to be the same or can they change?

Comment: The color can be changed so i need how to get the colors that exist in seg four on the datagridview

Comment: Seg four whats that? Also whats the condition that is needed for the cell colors? Is it certain values?

Comment: Also please show how you are creating the DataGridView.

Comment: From the look's of it these are images. To get the color we would have to grab the picture from the cell and grab the value's from the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the color from the object from that cell, we can use `CellContentClick` event of the `DataGridView`. The reason is to make sure we have something in that cell as if you just click in the cell it will not fire as **we do not want the back color/ default color of the cell**. I wrote up a quick little example that does just that. It is **tried and tested**.

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> Private Shared Function GetDC(hwnd As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    End Function

    <DllImport("user32.dll")> Private Shared Function ReleaseDC(hwnd As IntPtr, hdc As IntPtr) As Int32
    End Function

    <DllImport("gdi32.dll")> Private Shared Function GetPixel(hdc As IntPtr, nXPos As Integer, nYPos As Integer) As UInteger
    End Function

    'We can use this event as it will not fire until we actually click the object in the cell.
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentClick
        Try
            Dim _type As Type = DataGridView1.CurrentCell.GetType

            If _type IsNot Nothing Then
                If _type.Name = "DataGridViewImageCell" Then
                    Dim CurrentColor As Color = GetColor(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y)
                    Dim c As System.Drawing.Color = Nothing

                    For Each ob As System.Drawing.KnownColor In [Enum].GetValues(GetType(System.Drawing.KnownColor))
                        c = Color.FromKnownColor(ob)
                        'Do we have something?
                        If CurrentColor.ToArgb = c.ToArgb Then
                            'Do what you want with it...
                            MsgBox(c.Name)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            'Do something with your exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetColor(ByVal LocX As Integer, LocY As Integer) As System.Drawing.Color
        Dim _rColor As System.Drawing.Color = Color.White
        Dim hdc As IntPtr = GetDC(IntPtr.Zero)
        Dim pixel As UInteger = GetPixel(hdc, LocX, LocY)

        Try
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc)
            _rColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(pixel And &HFF), CInt(pixel And &HFF00) >> 8, CInt(pixel And &HFF0000) >> 16)
        Catch ex As Exception
            ReleaseDC(IntPtr.Zero, hdc)
            Return _rColor
        End Try

        Return _rColor
    End Function

End Class
```

As you can see I just used a `MsgBox` (I know it's old and should use `MessageBox`) but it was just for showing the color name anyways. I am not sure what you want to do with the color, but you have the color and everything else with it.

Comment: when i try again it turns out there are colors that do not unreadable, or do not appear the MsgBox ()

Comment: it's not out MsgBox but actually I need to get the color without a click,

Answer (score 0):

Have a hidden column that contains the color value used to draw the bitmap, When you want to find out the value interrogate the hidden column.

```
For i As Integer = 0 To sf.Categories.Count - 1
    Dim r As DataRow = dtCloned.NewRow
    Dim bmp As New Bitmap(50, 15)
    Dim g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Dim category As MapWinGIS.ShapefileCategory = sf.Categories.Item(i)
    ' save the calculated color in a variable
    Dim colorVal = scheme.GraduatedColor((i) / sf.Categories.Count)
    Dim Brush As New SolidBrush(ColorTranslator.FromOle(colorVal))
    g.FillRectangle(Brush, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, bmp.Width - 1, bmp.Height - 1)
    r(0) = bmp
    r(1) = category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1)
    r(2) = category.Name.Substring(category.Name.IndexOf("=") + 1)
    r(3) = colorVal ' save the value in a hidden cell
    dtCloned.Rows.Add(r)
Next

DataGVSymUnique.DataSource = dtCloned
    For Each c As DataGridViewColumn In DataGVSymUnique.Columns
        c.Width = 145
        c.ReadOnly = True
    Next
DataGVSymUnique.Columns("Legend").ReadOnly = False
```